# Distinct List<string[]> in c#

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I have a list of string[]:

```
List<string[]> EIndex;
```

Eindex list has 4 `string[]`

```
INPUT:           {0,John},{1,Mike},{2,John},{3,Tim}
Expected OUTPUT: {0,John},{1,Mike},{3,Tim}
```

I want to distinct the array based on index number 1 of `string[]` Like:

```
List<string[]> DistinctList = Eindex.Distinct(obj => obj[1]).ToList();
```

any suggestion?

Comment: 'Distinct the array'?  Could you give some example input and expected output?

Comment: Do you want to do that for the entire list, or strictly the first entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Distinct` takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` argument.  You can implement a custom comparer to equate your arrays by the item at their second index:

```
public class SecondIndexComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
{
    public bool Equals(string[] x, string[] y)
    {
        return x[1] == y[1];
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string[] obj)
    {
        return obj[1].GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
var distinctList = Eindex.Distinct(new SecondIndexComparer()).ToList();
```

See a working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cpv1i7

Comment: smooth. well done m8!